# The socket stop t Socket.accept() in Android for TCP Server

Tags: android, sockets

I try to create a Simple TCP Server on Android phone and waiting for client. 
I only want to implement the connection between `TCPServer` and `Client` , it doesn't need to transmit any data.

I have the another application for client , It use to connect to this `TCPServer`.
The code of `TCPServerthread` is like the following.

```
private class TCPServerThread implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

                //while loop
                while (true) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "TCPServerThread...while loop");
                    try {
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        Log.i(TAG, "TCPServerThread...socket.getInetAddress() = " + socket.getInetAddress());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(TAG, "First IOException");
                    }
                }
                //while loop end

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(TAG, "Second IOException");
            }
        }
    }
```

But it seems stop at `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();` and doesn't show the log of `TCPServerThread...socket.getInetAddress() =` when the `client` try to connect to this Server.

**DO I missing something for `TCPServer` ?**

**Is it mean the client doesn't connect to the Server when the code stop at `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();` ??**

**----------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------**

Update the process.

The `Server(Android Phone)` open the `WiFi-Hot-Spot`, it also open the `TCP-Server` like the above code.

After `Client` connect to `WiFi-Hot-Spot` , the `Client` and the `Server` are in the same network.

The `Client` will get a `IP address of gateway`, and the `Client` try to connect to this `IP address of gateway` by `TCP`.

So the `connection port` and `Server address` seems correct for `Client`.

Comment: If it does not pass serverSocket.accept() then no client connects. Find out why. Look in the client for errors. Please post the Client Logcat/stacktrace. Tell the setup you use. Enulator? Device? And so on.

Comment: @greenapps So the code of Server is correct ? and the problem is at Client ?

Comment: If all server code is correct i do not know. But for now it is obvious that your client does not connect. That can be because your setup is not according the used urls in the client. First: tell your set up as i already asked. Second: post the LogCat of the client. I already asked for that too.

Comment: @greenapps The code of client is not for Android , so I can not post the code. But I download the `Socket Protocol` App from Play store. The client can connect to `Socket Protocol` App.

Comment: TELL YOUR SETUP AND THE USED HOST:PORT

Comment: I create the Soft-AP mode and TCP Server on my phone , and the client connect to my phone. And then start TCP connect. The port is 50006.

Comment: So client and server are on the same phone/device.That is your setup.  Ok you provided port but forgot to tell which host(name) is used by the client to connect to the server. Further i do not understand `I create the Soft-AP mode `.

Comment: @greenapps The `Soft-AP` is `WiFi-Hot-Spot`. I have Update the process in the above content. I also download the `Socket Protocol` from play store. This App use to be a `TCP Server` , and my client can connect to this `TCP server`  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The setup is stil not clear. Further you first said "the client is not for android" so you had no code and no logcat. Now you told that client is on same phone/device. Suddenly you have an extra app that creates a hot spot and you have a gateway. You said "all ip address seem correct" but did not mention one. So what can we say now? You ask if i have ideas but if i ask you something then i get only half info. I asked for host and until now i know you use an ip. Please supply ALL ip addresses of used devices/hotspots/gateways/servers/clients and especially ip used by client. Logcat client

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but it seems that no one is connecting to your TCPserver.
To avoid this blocking situation on

```
     Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

you have to set the timeout option for your socket when you declare it

```
     serverSocket.setSoTimeout(mTime);
```

;)

Comment: But I have using a client try to connect to this Server. I also use the same client connect to another TCPServer APP , and it can connect